# Apache Nifi and rest api using template instantiate problem

Tags: python, rest, templates, apache-nifi

I am new to Apache Nifi would like to receive some help from you all, past 2 days I am trying to instantiate template into my process group using rest api through a python file. I am able to create process group and upload template but not able to instantiate it. Is it not possible? or is it possible then how to do it?

I tried to instantiate the template within process group of my nifi through python but it is showing
error: requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: